# What is the Set in V that represents the fraction 1/2?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Hopefully a simple question : As set theory includes only nested sequences of the empty set in the usual V, representation of an integer is easy. However what would the set that represents the number 1/2 look like precisely? I have seen some StackExchange responses describing how set theory handles Z, Q, R, Ordinal fractions, Surreal numbers etc. Presumably 1/2 is represented in different ways in these different number systems, but they went way over my head. I thought by asking what the set is that represents 1/2 would be straight forwards and kick off my trail to understand how set theory represents numbers less than a 'whole number'.

Comment: What about, the equivalence class of the pair of integers $(1,2)$?

Comment: (I think you're overthinking this:) One of the usual implementations of arithmetic in set theory goes as follows: the natural numbers get implemented as the finite ordinals in the obvious way; an integer is then an equivalence class of ordered pairs of finite ordinals with $(\alpha,\beta)\sim(\gamma,\delta)$ iff $\alpha+\delta=\beta+\gamma$ (intuitively $(\alpha,\beta)$ represents $\alpha-\beta$); a rational is then an equivalence class of ordered pairs of integers; and so on. *(And if you really want to have $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ etc., you do additional fudging.)*

Comment: Crucially, this is **not intended to be particularly natural**; the way $1\over 2$ gets implemeneted set theoretically is not intended to "feel one-half-like," it's just supposed to get the job done so to speak.

Comment: @ Noah Schweber : I was led to believe that doing Z, Q, R etc. was very complicated - see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711161/ordinal-fractions. An ordinal fraction is presumably a number less than a whole number ?